# using iTextSharp to iterate through PDF Table Rows

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

So, I have a Tagged PDF file with a label. As you can see for this screenshot:
[image: PDF Tags]

The /TABLE tag is there with all its /TR (Rows) and /TDs (cells).
Now I tried to get these objects by using this code:

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("test.pdf");
    PdfObject dict = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.XrefSize; i++)
    {
        PdfObject obj = reader.GetPdfObject(i);
        if (obj != null)
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(PdfDictionary))
            {
                dict = ((PdfDictionary)obj).GetAsDict(PdfName.TABLE);
                if (dict != null)
                {
                    //Do Something
                }
            }
    }
```

But it never catches them. What should I do?
I also used iText RUPS to debug the PDF file. I got this:
[image: iText RUPS output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reinvent the wheel. When I look at your code, I see the first step of a process that requires plenty of programming, but the work has already been done.

If you are using iText 5, please take a look at this [`TaggedPdfReaderTool`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/5.5.12/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/TaggedPdfReaderTool.html); if you are using iText 7, take a look at this [`TaggedPdfReaderTool`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/7.1.1/com/itextpdf/kernel/utils/TaggedPdfReaderTool.html).

I wrote this tool a long time ago in the context of my book "iText in Action - Second Edition." I wrote it as a proof of concept to show that I could convert an XML file to a Tagged PDF, and that I could convert the Tagged PDF back to the original XML file.

In iText 7, this tool was improved, and it's now used in our test suite. We create Tagged PDF's and in our tests, we convert them to XML. If the XML doesn't correspond with a "pre-baked" XML, the test fails.

You can use this tool to convert your Tagged PDF to an XML file, and then process that XML file to extract the table.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really great. I could save the tags to XML format then I can interpret them easily.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie. Thank you!
So using your idea, I tried in C# to convert my tagged pdf content into XML in a MemoryStream, 
so I can attempt to process the XML right after. Like this: 
`string myTaggedPdf = @"C:\temp\tagged.pdf"; 
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(myTaggedPdf));
TaggedPdfReaderTool taggedReader = new TaggedPdfReaderTool(doc); 
MemoryStream xmlInMemory = new MemoryStream();
taggedReader.ConvertToXml(xmlInMemory);  
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlInMemory);.`

Comment: But the last line throws an exception which says "The stream was not readable." 
I don't want to output the XML into a disk file, so how to properly put the XML representation of the tagged PDF content into a memory string? Thanks.  BTW, I just ordered your book from Amazon. Can't wait to read it.

Comment: I figured out. Instead of using TextReader, simply using this line to get a string representation of the MemoryStream: `var myXml = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(xmlStream.ToArray());`